# How to restart a python script when it crashes but doesn't die?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that needs to be running continuously on a linux server, it connects to a webSocket and retrieve a realtime feed of data.

After a dozens of hours, the script crashes but doesn't exit, it displays an error message about losing connection to the server and I have to manually Ctrl+C and run it again.

I am looking for a way to automatically (instantly) restart the python script once it crashes, how can one achieve this ?

Edit : this is the message I get when the script crashes

```
Server disconnected.
disconnect handler error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/engineio/client.py", line 496, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[event](*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 632, in _handle_eio_disconnect
    self._trigger_event('disconnect', namespace=n)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 550, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "python_script.py", line 29, in on_disconnect
    quit()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_sitebuiltins.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None
```

Here is the on_disconnect class parameter code :

```
@socketio_client.on('disconnect', namespace='/streaming')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Server disconnected.')
    quit()
```

I think I may have to call an external script to start a new instance of the python script.

Comment: take a look at supervisor for linux

Comment: Maybe put all the code in a try expect and when an error is raised just restart the script?

Comment: Please provide some code, the "problem" you've described is very generic and potential solutions therefore broad. Without a concrete piece of code to look at, you keep us guessing about factors sorrounding the issue and thus make it much harder than necessary for us to help you out.

Comment: as omercotkd says, just wrap the are that causes an error in a try function so that if there *is* an error, you can just rerun the code without anything happening.